# "::drem has not been declared" when compiling tvmet library in MinGW/GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw

I have a legacy project that's written in C++ and targets gcc and depends on a library called [tvmet](http://tvmet.sourceforge.net/).  I'm trying to compile it in MinGW, but I'm getting this error:

```
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../include/tvmet/BinaryFunctionals.h: 
  In static member function 'static tvmet::Fcnl_drem<T1, T2>::value_type   
  tvmet::Fcnl_drem<T1, T2>::apply_on(T1, T2)':
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../include/tvmet/BinaryFunctionals.h:230:1: 
  error: '::drem' has not been declared
```

For more background:  tvmet uses a preprocessor macro to generate templated structs as follows:

```
/** \class Fcnl_drem        BinaryFunctionals.h "tvmet/BinaryFunctionals.h" */
/** \class Fcnl_hypot       BinaryFunctionals.h "tvmet/BinaryFunctionals.h" */
/** \class Fcnl_jn      BinaryFunctionals.h "tvmet/BinaryFunctionals.h" */
/** \class Fcnl_yn      BinaryFunctionals.h "tvmet/BinaryFunctionals.h" */

#define TVMET_IMPLEMENT_MACRO(NAME)                 \
template <class T1, class T2>                       \
struct Fcnl_##NAME : public BinaryFunctional {              \
  typedef typename PromoteTraits<T1, T2>::value_type    value_type; \
                                \
  static inline                             \
  value_type apply_on(T1 lhs, T2 rhs) {     \
    return TVMET_GLOBAL_SCOPE(NAME)(lhs, rhs);              \
  }                                 \
                                \
  static                                \
  void print_xpr(std::ostream& os, std::size_t l=0) {           \
    os << IndentLevel(l)                        \
       << "Fcnl_" << #NAME << "<T1="                    \
       << typeid(T1).name() << ", T2=" << typeid(T2).name() << ">," \
       << std::endl;                            \
  }                                 \
};

TVMET_IMPLEMENT_MACRO(drem)
TVMET_IMPLEMENT_MACRO(hypot)
TVMET_IMPLEMENT_MACRO(jn)
TVMET_IMPLEMENT_MACRO(yn)

#undef TVMET_IMPLEMENT_MACRO
```

It's essentially substituting the names of existing math functions.  The problem here seems to be that "drem" is not defined.  "drem" appears to be part of glibc, but other glibc functions like "fmod" seem to work ok.  What could be the issue here?  I can provide more info if requested.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you including <math.h> or <cmath> that is where drem() is defined.

Comment: Yes, I included it, but it's still not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague found the problem: drem is not supported on MinGW.

http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/gnulib.html#drem

Somehow I missed it.  It doesn't seem very easy to google for drem!